# catalog price rule plus day and minus day

Tags: catalog, catalog-price-rules

I am odd why magento want to make rule date contain three date (current day, - 1 days before, + 1 days after). Will you tell me any purpose from the following code? Because we have not setup cron so and i don't want to setup cron.

Answer (score 1):

catalogprice rules are valid for days. Magento creates a row for every day a rule is valid. When you apply rules, a rule for yesterday, today and tomorrow is generated.

The cron creates every night, the entry for the next day/day after.

So to use this feature you have to set up a cron. There is no atlernative, because that's how things work.